# Identity 2.0 UserTokenProvider and its purposes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am working with Identity 2.0 to reset a user's password. The following snippets work independently:

The following code generates a token using UserTokenProvider with PasswordReset purpose and validates it.

```
var token = await _userManager.UserTokenProvider.GenerateAsync("PasswordReset", _userManager, user);
var IsValid = await _userManager.UserTokenProvider.ValidateAsync("PasswordReset", token, _userManager, user);
```

The following code generates a password reset token using UserManager's built in function and resets one's password

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, token, "newPassword");
```

The following code is what I am using as a UserTokenProvider:

```
var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("AppName");
this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, long>(provider.Create("PasswordReset"));
```

What I would like to accomplish is divided in 3 steps:

Generate a token (works)

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

Check if it is valid. If it is, the user will insert a new password (works)

```
var IsValid = await _userManager.UserTokenProvider.ValidateAsync("PasswordReset", token, _userManager, user);
```

Reset user's password (doesn't work since the purpose is different)

```
_userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, token, "newPassword");
```

The problem is: apparently, ResetPasswordAsync uses a built in Password Reset Purpose (called "Options.Tokens.ChangeEmailTokenProvider" from its source code) and I am unable to access it.

Could somebody elucidate me how to solve this? I want to validate the token generated before I allow the user to change the password.

Thanks in advance.